# I am getting an error when I load Pandas and Numpy in

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I am getting below error when execute below:

```
import numpy as np
```

**The full stack trace:**

```
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 142, in <module>
    from . import add_newdocs

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <module>
    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .type_check import *

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\type_check.py", line 11, in <module>
    import numpy.core.numeric as _nx

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    from . import multiarray

ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like some of the dependencies are missing for the package `numpy`. The DLL load failed error points towards either incorrectly installed and/or missing files for package numpy. You should just try installing numpy again through Anaconda CLI using the following command:

```
conda install numpy
```

This works most of the times, if your python environments are sorted correctly. Do make sure that the python installation you're using for Anaconda, is the same one as your coding environment. Conflicting versions can sometimes lead to corrupted packages.

You could also try the following command to update the Anaconda Environment just to make sure that the installations are up to date, and not conflicting with older versions..

```
conda update -y -all
```

Comment: I did all of that with no luck. I checked the environments and they are both using Anaconda.

Comment: How did you install numpy in that environment?

Comment: conda install numpy